# Matlab- put border around sliding window

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

Hi I have code which puts a sliding window over an image in Matlab. If the pixels within the sliding window meet certain conditions then I need to highlight that sliding window on the original image by putting a rectangle around it.

Can anyone explain to me how to do this?

Thanks.

```
 if average>200
         N2=8;
         info2 = repmat(struct, ceil(size(Z, 1) / N2), ceil(size(Z, 2) / N2)); 
         for row1 = 1:N2:size(Z, 1)%loop through each pixel in the 8x8 window
             for col1 = 1:N2:size(Z, 2)
                 x = (row1 - 1) / N2 + 1;
                 y = (col1 - 1) / N2 + 1;

                 imgWindow2 = Z(row1:min(end,row1+N2-1), col1:min(end,col1+N2-1));
                 average2 = mean(imgWindow2(:)); %calculate mean intensity of pixels
                 window2(x,y).average=average2;
                % display(window2(x,y).average);


                % if the intensity of the 8x8 window is greater than
                % 210 then considered suspicious-
                 if average2>210
                 %%%% THEN HIGHLIGH THIS WINDOW ON THE ORG IMAGE (Z)
                 end 
             end
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display this in a figure, you can use the `imrect` function. If you want to draw the rectangle into the image itself, and you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, you can use `insertShape` or `insertObjectAnnotation` functions.

Comment: Thanks! How do I specify where on the original image to place this rectangle? I have updated my question so that you can see how I have created my sliding window.

Comment: Look at the doc for these functions. They all take the rectangle specified as [x, y, width, height], where [x,y] are the coordinates of the upper-left corner.

Comment: Tired this Z1  = insertShape(Z, 'circle', [x y 8], 'LineWidth', 5); using the x and y position for the window shown in the code above but I am getting an error : Error in BeastSeg2 (line 209)
                                   Z1  = insertShape(Z, 'circle', [150 280 35], 'LineWidth', 5);

Comment: What was the error?  My guess is that you may have an older version of MATLAB, which doesn't support the 'LineWidth' parameter.

Comment: yes sorry forgot to show the error : Argument 'LineWidth' did not match any valid parameter of the parser. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Just don't use LineWidth. You will get a circle 1 pixel thick.

Comment: thanks. A rectangle now prints on the image but not in the correct position. I have posted a new question, I wonder if you could help me with this?

Comment: Check that you didn't switch x and y. As for your new question, a link would help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244167/matlab-put-rectangle-on-image,  sorry forgot the link the first time.